# The value of an expression involving the imaginary cube root of unity

Tags: sequences-and-series

> The value of the expression $1\cdot(2-\omega)(2-\omega^2)+2\cdot(3-\omega)(3-\omega^2)+...+(n-1)\cdot(n-\omega)(n-\omega^2)$, where $\omega$ is an imaginary cube root of unity, is ...

My attempt: $r$-th term $T_r=\sum r\cdot(r+1-\omega)(r+1-\omega^2))$. On simplifying, I get $T_r=\sum r^3+\sum r^2 +\sum r$. On summing it to $n-1$ terms, I get, $S=n(n-1)(3n^2+n+4)/12$. But the answer has been given as $\frac14n^2(n+1)^2-n.$ I wonder what I did wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your work it should be
$$T_r=\sum r\cdot(r+1-\omega)(r+1-\omega^2)=\sum r^3+3\sum r^2 +3\sum r.$$
Could you consider this correction and finish your computation?

Answer (score 1):

With $\omega^3=1,\,\omega\ne1\implies\omega+\omega^2=-1$, by my calculation $$S=\sum_{r=1}^{n-1}r(r+1-\omega)(r+1-\omega^2)\\=\sum_rr((r+1)^2-(r+1)(\omega+\omega^2)+\omega^3)\\=\sum_rr(r^2+3r+3)\\=\frac14 n^2(n-1)^2+\frac12 n(n-1)(2n-1)+\frac32 n(n-1)\\=\frac14 n^2(n+1)^2-n^3+n^3-\frac32 n^2+\frac12 n+\frac32 n^2-\frac32 n=\frac14 n^2(n+1)^2-n.$$I'd need to see more of your work to know where you went wrong, but I suspect you used $n$ in certain formulae instead of $n-1$. For example, note that $$\sum_{r=1}^kr^3=\frac14 k^2(k+1)^2\implies\sum_{r=1}^{n-1}r^3=\frac14 (n-1)^2n^2.$$

Answer (score 1):

$$
(r+1 - 1)(r+1-\omega)(r+1-\omega^2) = (r+1)^3 - 1
$$